# CSS animation in a single HTML element

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS loader:

http://jsfiddle.net/SPFgH/3/

**HTML**:

```
<div id="fountainG"> <i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#fountainG {
    position:relative;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 120px);
    width:240px;
    height:29px
}
#fountainG i {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background-color:#A300A3;
    width:29px;
    height:29px;
    animation-name:bounce_fountainG;
    animation-duration:1.3s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-direction:linear;
    transform:scale(.3);
    border-radius:19px;
}
#fountainG i:nth-child(1) {
    left:0;
    animation-delay:0.52s;
}
#fountainG i:nth-child(2) {
    left:30px;
    animation-delay:0.65s;
}
#fountainG i:nth-child(3) {
    left:60px;
    animation-delay:0.78s;
}
#fountainG i:nth-child(4) {
    left:90px;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.91s;
    -ms-animation-delay:0.91s;
}
#fountainG i:nth-child(5) {
    left:120px;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.04s;
    -ms-animation-delay:1.04s;
}
#fountainG i:nth-child(6) {
    left:150px;
    animation-delay:1.17s;
}
#fountainG i:nth-child(7) {
    left:180px;
    animation-delay:1.3s;
}
#fountainG i:nth-child(8) {
    left:210px;
    animation-delay:1.43s;
}
@keyframes bounce_fountainG {
    0% {
        transform:scale(1);
        background-color:#A300A3;
    }
    100% {
        transform:scale(.3);
        background-color:#999999;
    }
}
```

I need to convert it to a CSS animation with a single HTML element.
I may use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to add 2 of the 8 child elements, but how can I add all the 8 elemenets?

Comment: This is really an unclear question.

Comment: BTW You're not using the conventional `animation-delay` etc, only `webkit` and `ms`, so it's not working on FF.

Comment: what is not clear? I want this animation with just one HTML element instead of have it with 9 elements, I'd like to know if is possible in some way using CSS only solutions. I don't care about cross-compatibility at the moment, is not the point of the question.

Comment: As far as I know it's impossible.

Comment: Can you use javascript to initialise it? If so, do you have any frameworks available to you (eg: jQuery)?

Comment: I'd prefer use only CSS and HTML, it's supposed to be an animation shown when the page is opened and the animation goes over the rest of the page, using javascript it would be slower..

Comment: Do you have to have exactly eight items?

Comment: honestly I just need a nice animation with a single element, but would be interesting find a way to use this animation with a single element, I can find single-element animations on google easily

Comment: You could convert the animation to a GIF and set it as the background on an element. I'm pretty sure that is the only way you'd be able to achieve this animation with a single HTML element.

Comment: You could do it using a canvas as well

Comment: but it requires javascript

Comment: I know that but the same effect using only one element without javascript is only possible by turning it into a gif like BigMacAttack said. I was provided another possible option using one element

Comment: yup I guess the GIF is the only solution..

Comment: Personally I think a canvas would do you better because you can edit it easily but it's just an opinion

Comment: Please explain your question properly

Answer (score 0):

If you need the animation to work with just one I tag

```
#fountainG {
    position:relative;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 120px);
    width:240px;
    height:29px
}
#fountainG i {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background-color:#A300A3;
    width:29px;
    height:29px;
    animation-name:bounce_fountainG;
    animation-duration:1.3s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-direction:linear;
    transform:scale(.3);
    border-radius:19px;
}
#fountainG i:nth-child(1) {
    left:0;
    animation-delay:0.52s;
}

@keyframes bounce_fountainG {
    0% {
        transform:scale(1);
        background-color:#A300A3;
    }
    100% {
        transform:scale(.3);
        background-color:#999999;
    }
}
```

try this and see, have you tried

Comment: Worked actually, but look is maintained only when you add a few I tags, thanks for this animation useful for me too!